# Printing in Python -- inherently functional?

Tags: python

Learned Python for a project at work (which is cool, b/c now I can fiddle with Anki!).  In general, I really like the language.  Not as intense as Perl, and although I haven't played with its libraries very much so far, it seems every bit as powerful as Perl with less thinking.

One of the very few things I'm NOT fond of is Python feels like it can't make up its mind between whether its procedural or object oriented.  One example of this which is causing me grief is printing.  For example, this causes an error:

```
f = 5.0
print 'The value is ' + f
```

You need to explicitly convert f to a string.  Or else resort to one of the least object-oriented paradigms since 1969:

```
f = 5.0
print 'The value is %f' % f
```

What's going on here?  I claim that if Python won't print that first snippet, it's only because Python isn't trying hard enough, not because it can't.  Let's say that numerical values in Python aren't "objectified" like Java's Integer or Double classes.  Maybe they're simply numbers that don't know how to return their stringified representation when asked.  Python certainly keeps track of their type.  I know this because type(f) tells me so.  So why not go that extra mile and do the conversion for me?  If I was worried about nanoseconds of execution time, I wouldn't be using Python in the first place.

Even languages whose OOP nature is a lipstick-on-a-pig situation, like Perl or VB6 can field this with grace.

OK, sorry.  I didn't mean for this to be a rant.  What I really wanted was to ask for help.

Is there a library, maybe some user written code, maybe a wrapper function that will simply allow me to do something like this:

```
f = 5.0
g = (1, 2, 3)
h = [a, b, c]
print 'f: ' + ', ' + f + ', g: ' + g + ', h: ' + h
```

without having to do the conversion to string myself?  I'm allowed to be lazy. I'm a programmer.  It's my birthright...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel printing strings has something to do with procedural or object-oriented programming (or functional programming, which you seem to have conflated with procedural?)

Comment: Python is dynamically **but strongly** typed; implicit conversion doesn't happen. Note that most modern Python code will be using `'The value is {:f}'.format(f)`, which is perhaps more explicitly OOP, rather than `'The value is %f' % f`.

Comment: Please don't turn python into JavaScript.  Some of us *want* to be the ones to explicitly decide when numbers get turned into strings so we don't have to deal with all of the bugs that implicit conversions cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're talking about implicit type conversion, which has absolutely nothing to do with object-oriented programming.  Every paradigm has languages with and without implicit conversion, python being an obvious example.

The question is why.  Implicit conversion can be convenient, but it comes with the cost of unexpected behavior under certain conditions.  [This video](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) highlights some of the more humorous ones.  Some language designers feel the convenience is worth the cost and some don't.  That's why we have so many languages.  [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) lists "explicit is better than implicit" as one of its guiding principles.

What you *can* do in python is create a function that converts each of its arguments.  In fact, many built-in functions already work that way.  For example, you can do:

```
print('f:', f, ', g:', g, ', h:', h)
"f: {}, g: {}, h: {}".format(f, g, h)
```

You can also use the functional side of python to convert a bunch of disparate variables to strings:

```
map(str, [f, g, h])
```

Of course, you can also create your own functions that use `*args` and `**kwargs` and call `str()` on all of them.

You have lots of very good options here.  Don't complain because they don't look exactly like another language you're more accustomed to.

Answer (score 13):

No, there is no library that allows you to concatenate strings and numbers. This is precisely *because* of the object oriented aspects of Python: The behavior of addition is determined by methods of the objects being added, and these classes are closed for modification (you can't replace their methods, though you inherit from them and override the methods).

> I claim that if Python won't print that first snippet, it's only because Python isn't trying hard enough, not because it can't.

That's not completely wrong. "Not trying hard enough" is misleading though, read on.

> Let's say that numerical values in Python aren't "objectified" like Java's Integer or Double classes. Maybe they're simply numbers that don't know how to return their stringified representation when asked.

It clearly does know that: `some_number.__str__()` (though you'd generally write `str(some_number)` instead).

> So why not go that extra mile and do the conversion for me?

Because the designers are of the opinion that such implicit conversions are more trouble than they're worth. It makes coding error (such as forgetting to convert numeric input from text to an actual number type) silently produce wrong results. It also contributes to beginners being confused about the actual types of their data. Plus a million other minor reasons.

> If I was worried about nanoseconds of execution time, I wouldn't be using Python in the first place.

I don't know where you think performance enters the picture. An implicit conversion might actually be faster, or equally fast. In any case, it is telling that you presuppose such a stupid reason for the decision.

Finally, nothing about that behavior is special to `print`. Addition in a `print` "context" behaves exactly as anywhere else, because there is no special case, `print` just accepts a series of expressions and evaluates them as any other expression is evaluated. This is doubly obvious in Python 3 (or when using `from __future__ import print_function`) where `print` is just another built-in function. Python doesn't deal with nonsense like functions being able to affect the evaluation of their arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should do what you want.

```
def zprint(*args):         # *args accepts and stores infinite args in a list 
    stuff_to_print = ""    
    for i in args:         # iterate through args adding what you want to print
        stuff_to_print += str(i)
    print stuff_to_print   # print the results
```

Here is examples input and output:

```
>>> l=4
>>> zprint(l, "helloworld", False)
4helloworldFalse
```

Notice the function also accepts bools.

You're welcome if this helped!

Answer (score 2):

Python objects **can** be turned into strings, in fact, it's built in.
Just try:

```
n.__str__()
```

Python doesn't do anything unless it's explict.

`str(n)` just calls `n.__str__`

If you subclassed `int` you could get a list-number...

In fact, here it is:

```
class list_number(int):
    _theshadowl = ["wow","wowzeez","awesome"]
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i = i
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self._theshadowl[key]+" is a happy word"
    def __setitem__(self,key):
        return "You want to change the shadows!?!? No way!"
    def __call__(self,**args):
        print "Get out of here "+str(args)+", you argument slime!"
```

Python's weird.